# Parse values and get count from JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have this JSON in a file:

```
[
{
    "contributors": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "created_at": "Fri Aug 04 21:12:59 +0000 2017",
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "media": [
            {
                "display_url": "pic.twitter.com",
                "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com",
                "id": 893569740,
                "id_str": "893027840",
                "indices": [
                    16,
                    39
                ],
                "media_url": "http://pbs.tw.com/media",
                "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/1.jpg",
                "sizes": {
                    "large": {
                        "h": 581,
                        "resize": "fit",
                        "w": 400
                    }
                },
                "source_status_id": 20925697,
                "url": "https://ca.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    "id": 343288
}
]
```

I wrote this script which prints all of the json text:

```
with open('tweets.json') as json_data:
data = json.load(json_data)
print (data)
```

How can I parse the file and count the number of IDs present in the JSON file using Python?

Comment: What do you mean "number of IDs present"?

Comment: What have you tried?  You should attempt to answer your question and post the code for help.  `data` is a list of python dicts so it's just a matter of iterating and counting.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information, where can you get multiple `id`s?
 E.g. if each `id` is in its own top-level dictionary then `len(data)` would give you count of entries, if there can be multiple `id`s in `media` then `sum(len(d['entities']['media']) for d in data)`

Comment: I'm not sure if you pasted it in correctly, but the `}` on the 2nd to last line closes the "entities" object, not the `{` on on the 2nd line, so you need to add another closing `}` before it in order for the JSON file to properly be parsed.

Comment: My JSON file is a huge file. This is just a snippet of it. And i want to print the value of "id" in entire JSON file. How do I do so?

Comment: As @AChampion wrote, since `id` is unique (its a tweet id) the amount of `id`s will be equal to the length of the data so `len(data)` will give you that answer.

Comment: Thank you @droravr and @AChampion. Also, is there a way i can print all those `id`s?

Comment: @NehaShah, simple `for` loop will do that for you - 
`for tweet in data: print tweet['id']`